# Amazon S3 signed urls accessible from outside world

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

So we have a use case where we need to be able to download the `S3` files from the outside world on the internet. For this we are creating `s3 pre signed url` as below. My doubt is how can we access this on the internet? Are these urls accessible by default on the internet. Or do we need to create a proxy.

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<filename><some other parameters>
```

Comment: That's not a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html).

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are showing is not a Pre-signed URL. A Pre-signed URL look like this:

https://bucketxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/note.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230117T153509Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3599&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA33JWY3BX2TYWxxxxxxxxxxx%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e55142af548e46fc2870bb03331d0e9aa9ffbd21xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Once you generate a valid Pre-signed URL, you do not need a proxy. A user can download the object in the given time window - which you define when you create **GetObjectPresignRequest** .

```
GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest = GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                   .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                   .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                   .build();
```

You can see the proper way to create a pre-signed URL using AWS SDK for Java v2 in the **AWS Code Github** here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectPresignedUrl.java

TO read more about using the AWS SDK for Java v2 to create them, see this topic in the **AWS Java V2 Developer Guide**.

[Working with Amazon S3 presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's what I meant with pre signed url. So these urls are accessible on the internet right?

Comment: Yes: "You can use a S3Presigner object to sign an Amazon S3 SdkRequest so that it’s executed without requiring authentication on the part of the caller. For example, assume Alice has access to an S3 object, and she wants to temporarily share access to that object with Bob. Alice can generate a pre-signed GetObjectRequest object to secure share with Bob so that he can download the object without requiring access to Alice’s credentials."

Comment: the explanation from the doc

Comment: Just because it's a stumbling point people hit surprisingly often:  Be aware the presigned URLs have a lifespan of up to a week.  If you need a URL to be valid for longer than that, you'll need some other solution.